# The graph comprises vertices only/solely/exclusively/entirely from one of the sets A and B.

Tags: adverbs

are the adverbs interchangeable in this case, or would you prefer one over another?

I want to state that the graph does not comprise any vertices other than the ones that are contained in one of the sets A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Only*, *solely* and *exclusively* act in essentially the same way in this case - all of the terms mean that all of the vertices come from either set A or set B and not from anywhere else.

This would not be true in all contexts - in legal contexts sole license and exclusive license are not exactly the same, the former means that only one person (the receiver of the license) has license, where as the latter means that the grantor of the license and the receiver of the license both have license, but no one else does.

*Entirely* does not suit in this context, as it refers to a quantity, rather than a number. The vertices are not a quantity of something (such as water), they are cardinal set of things (in this case, a set of some number of vertices).

To my ears, this is in any case a slightly clunky way to put it, you could just as easily leave out the adverb, and use a quantifier instead, e.g. "All vertices comprising the graph are from set A or set B"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can that be rephrased to "All vertices comprising the graph are **from either set A or B**."?

Meaning, the vertices of the graph are contained in both sets A and B, that is, they are contained in the intersection of sets A and B.

Comment: If you want the meaning to be that they come from the **intersection** of set A and set B, then the phrasing should be something like **...are members of both set A and set B**. if you write **from set A and set B** then it is not clear.

If you want to say that they are from the **unification** of set A and set B, then you could write **from set A or set B** - this is intuitively taken as an inclusive _or_. If you say **either from set A or set B** then it sounds as if you mean the union minus the intersection - i.e. elements in set A but not B or in set B but not A, or the exclusive _or_.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that the graph comprises vertices from the elements of set A or the elements of set B, but not both, go with exclusively (in logic, the related binary relation is "exclusive or" or "xor", thus most English speakers with a background in logic will pick up on what you mean). Technically speaking, from a logic perspective, the other ones should be fine if you really want to use them for some reason, though. 
If you mean to say that all of the vertices are from A or B (inclusively), then you should change it to "The graph comprises vertices only/solely/exclusively/entirely from the sets A or B" or "The graph comprises vertices only/solely/exclusively/entirely from the union of the sets A and B" (in other words, remove the qualifier "one of"). 
If you mean to say that all of the vertices are from both the sets A and B (in other words, from the intersection of A and B), then go with "The graph solely comprises vertices from both set A and set B".